# when I use global scope variable without 'var', its showing me Error. why?

Tags: javascript

See my example code below

```
<script>
alert(a); // undefined
alert(b); // It is Error, b is not defined.
var a=1;
b=10;
</script>
```

When both variable a and b are in global scope, why I am getting error message for b. But there is no error message for variable a ? what is the reason ?

can anyone please explain me ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first `alert` shows `undefined` because the `var` statements are *hoisted* to the top of the enclosing scope, in other words, `var` statements and `function` declarations are made before the actual code is executed, in the parsing stage.

When your code is executed, is equivalent to:

```
var a;    // declared and initialized with `undefined` before the code executes
alert(a); // undefined
alert(b); // ReferenceError, b is not declared.
a=1;
b=10;
```

The second `alert` doesn't even executes, trying to access `b` gives you a `ReferenceError` because you never declared it, and you are trying to access it.

That's how the identifier resolution process works in Javascript, if an identifier is not found in all the scope chain, a `ReferenceError` exception is thrown.

Also, you should know that assigning an identifier *without declaring it first* (as `b = 10`) does not technically declares a *variable*, even in the global scope, the effect may be similar (and it seems to work), at the end the identifier ends as a property of the global object, for example:

```
var a = 1;
b = 10;

// Similar effect:
window.a; // 1
window.b; // 10
```

But this is just due the fact that the global object is the top-most environment record of the scope chain.

Another difference between the two above is that the identifier declared with `var` produces a non-configurable property on the global object (cannot be deleted), e.g.:

```
delete window.a; // false
delete window.b; // true
```

Also, if you are in the scope of a function, and you make an assignment to an undeclared identifier, it will end up being a property of the global object, just like in the above example, whereas the `var` statement will create a *local variable*, for example:

```
(function(){
  var a = 1;
  b = 10;
})();

typeof window.a; // 'undefined', was locally scoped in the above function
typeof window.b; // 'number', leaked, an unintentional global
```

I would really discourage make assignments to undeclared identifiers, always use `var` to *declare* your variables, moreover, this has been *disallowed* on ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode, assignments made to undeclared identifiers throw a `ReferenceError`:

```
(function(){'use strict'; b = 10;})(); // throws a ReferenceError
```

Comment: Clearest concrete example of hoisting I've ever seen.

Comment: Could you point me/everyone to an explanation for why this is implemented this way?

Comment: @Liviu Declaring a global variable by using it without a `var` was intended as a convenience for beginners so when they wrote hello world  and forgot the var some unintelligible compiler errors would not spit out.

Comment: @Liviu, if you wonder why ECMAScript implements *hosting*, IMO is due how the concepts of *execution contexts* work in the language. When entering an execution context the variable environment is initialized with `function` declarations, variables and function arguments (if the execution context we are entering is "function code"). This is made to *prepare all the necessary data* of the execution context to the next stage, the code execution.